# Implement Single Sign on in WSO2 API Manager though a external IDP for a single application

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I want to configure WSO2 API Manager with SSO,
    the IDP will be an external identity provider. (Example: Siteminder)
    This configuration should be done for a single application configured in WSO2 API Manager Store.

Comment: Do you want to manage keys of a particular application created in Store with an external identity provider? Is that your requirement?

Comment: No I want to integrate WSO2 API Manager with an external SiteMinder. So that the authentication happens in SiteMinder and the access token generation happens in WSO2 API manager

Answer (score 1):

You may follow the approach mentioned below:

1. When you generate tokens for an application in API Store, it will create a **service provider**. You can view it in Management Console under Service Providers.
2. Create an Identity Provider with the relevant configurations of SiteMinder (Give OIDC or SAML configs under **Federated Authenticators** section, as per your requirement)
3. Edit the **Service Provider** which created for the application. Select Federated Authentication and select the created **Identity Provider** under Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration.

Further, you may use custom event handler [1] to change the authentication **Identity Provider** during Service Provider creation

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Writing+a+Custom+Event+Handler